# How to proceed for initializing repo in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, repository

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and working towards building cwm recovery for an android mobile from source. As a part of the procedure I want to sync repo prior to which repo is to be initialized.In which folder should repo be initialised?I have `cm12` as my working folder , so should i give the command

```
 $ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

in `prasanna@prasanna-Aspire-4736Z:` or in `prasanna@prasanna-Aspire-4736Z:~/cm12` ?

I am a newbie in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize a repo with

```
$ repo init -u <URL> [<OPTIONS>]
```

it will install the repo in the current directory. So if you want the repo in `cm12`, you have to `cd` in to the working directory you have created i.e  `cm12`.

From the official [documentation](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html):

> `repo init` installs Repo in the current directory. This creates a
>   `.repo/` directory that contains Git repositories for the Repo source
>   code and the standard Android manifest files. The `.repo/` directory
>   also contains `manifest.xml`, which is a symlink to the selected
>   manifest in the `.repo/manifests/` directory.

Comment: Yeah. I feel like a big fool now. I had to delete .repo whose size was as huge as 72 Mb and start afresh by making directory cm12 after dleting cm12, then going into the working folder i initialized the repo. Now I am syncing repo, which I hope will succeed this time.

Comment: there is a small correction, the size of .repo just before deleting was 74 GB, not 74 MB.